# Cloudblobcontainer.common.cs not found

Tags: azure, containers

I'm working on a website for Azure, on a local dev environment. When I try to the method: Container.GetBlockBlobReference I get an error:

Cloudblobcontainer.common.cs not found

My feeling is that the cloud storage url I'm using is incorrect. Please assist and advise where I configure this and where I get the link to point it to.

Comment: Can you add some code? How do you initialize your storage account and container?

Comment: Here is the initialization:
                    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(string.Format(source + ".{0}", "txt"));

Comment: I meant a bit longer code sample. Is it something like this?

   var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount;
            var blobclient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var container = blobclient.GetContainerReference("test-container");
            container.CreateIfNotExists();
            var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("first/second/blob.blob");`